# How to get link with multiline caption in vaadin framework

Tags: java, web, frameworks, vaadin

i have  a requirement of having a link component with mutliline caption

```
new Users??? //line 1 of same link
Register Here //line 2 of  same link
```

i am using reindeer theme for my application
how to do it ????

Comment: Whyt not just put two button-links below each other?

Comment: I need to mention that the caption for the Link doesn't undergo any formatting. It is just inserted as plain text. To solve this issue you would need extend LinkConnector. I can try to come up with some code but only if you consider that it is absolutely necessary, and that you can't resort to just putting two links instead of one.

Comment: yeah two button-links pointing to same url i know.... but is it not possible to achieve with only one link with \n or something else ???